# RTPS_HISTORY ERROR

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a RTI CONNEXT  installation on my machine. Now whenever I run a node in ROS2, e.g. `talker.py`, I always get a runtime error : `[RTPS_HISTORY Error] Change payload size of 'n'>5000 bytes is larger than the history payload size of '5000' bytes and cannot be resized. ->function add_change`

I have already consulted [this](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps/issues/68) documentation but could not get the solution for it.

Any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298610/rtps_history-error/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can happen when using Fast-RTPS and Connext with a message in a particular size range. Long term `rmw_fastrtps_cpp` should be updated to use [this enhancement](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS/issues/213) . In the short term there are a couple options

1. Use `rmw_connext_cpp` for the ROS2 rmw implementation by setting the environment variable `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION`, or
2. Configure Connext to not send type matching messages larger than 5000 bytes. `rmw_connext_cpp` disables `TypeCode` to avoid this ([see this issue](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_connext/pull/288) ).

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-07-26**:
for the moment, i used the first option i.e. settting the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION = rmw_connext_cpp` and it worked. Thankyou

**Comment by [coatwolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/117662/coatwolf/) on 2022-09-13**:
I know this thread is old -- buy any tips for solving this problem in the context of MicroROS (using the Arduino library)?

I'm trying to use a custom message type containing a string and a float32, and it was actually working fine for me (I was able to echo MicroROS topic via agent), but something must have happened because now when I try to echo the topic I am seeing:

```
2022-09-13 20:48:29.787 [RTPS_READER_HISTORY Error] Change payload size of '16' bytes is larger than the history payload size of '11' bytes and cannot be resized. -> Function can_change_be_added_nts
```

Not quite sure where to go from here...